# Proof that x^3 = 2 has a real solution using completeness theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am trying to prove that x^3 = 2 has a solution in the real numbers using completeness theorem. I was trying to base myself on a proof seen before for x^2 =2 but it seems to have many steps that are unique to itself, and dont apply generally to other x^n = 2 problems. So far I understand I have to have a set {x | x^3 <2} and to prove its bounded, then using completeness I set a sup and show that that sup is my answer. But im just lost as to the manipulation and steps needed to show those results.

Thank you in advance.
EDIT: by completeness theorem I mean that every bounded set in the real number line has a supremum and infimum.

Comment: What "completeness theorem"? Gödel's??

Comment: I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: One needs essentially to reconstruct the proof of the Intermediate Value Thm. using the completeness property of real numbers.  But since $x^3$ is a *monotone* function of $x$, there are some shortcuts you can take.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with - proving bounded or finding sup?

Comment: Proving boundness first. But even if I were to do it, not sure what my next step is. I think I need to show that sup = x s.t x^3 =2

Answer (score 1):

First of all, show that $x\mapsto x^3$ is strictly monotone increasing, i.e. $x<y\iff x^3<y^3$ for any $x,y\in\Bbb R$
(you might want to split it into the following cases: $x,y<0$, $\,x<0\le y$ and $\,0\le x,y$).

Now, take $S:=\{x\in\Bbb R:x^3< 2\}$. 
This is bounded, because e.g. $x\in S\implies x^3< 2< 8=2^3\implies x< 2$.
Let $s:=\sup S$, then for $\varepsilon=\frac1n$ there's an $x_n\in S$ with $\ s\ge x_n>s-\frac1n$, thus $\ \lim_nx_n=s$, implying
$$s^3\ =\ \lim_nx_n^3\ \le\ 2$$
On the other hand, for every $x\in S$ there is an $y\in S$ such that $y>x$, so $s\in S$ would contradict the supremum property. 
If you want to explicitly find such $y$, you can use estimations like
$$y^3-x^3=(y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)<12(y-x)$$
which holds since $x,y\in S$, hence $x,y<2$ (and we can consider only positive $x,y$).

All in all it means $s^3\le 2$ but $s^3\not<2$, so $s^3=2$.

Comment: Thank you! This helps alot

Comment: At the beginning, no need to split in cases, it is straightforward: assume $\;y>x\;$ , then
$$y^3-x^3=(y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)>0$$
because $\;y>x\;$ and the other factor is always positive (just refer to it as a quadratic in $\;x\;or\;y\;$ and check its determinant is negative)